# Adding two columns of lists together as new column in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe

I have constructed a pandas dataframe that contains some columns that are composed of lists as so:

```
   A   B    C   List_A     List_B
   10  10   5   [0, 5, 1]  [10, 12, 0]
   5   7    8   [6, 7, 4]  [5, 2, 1]
  ...
```

What I would like to do is to add an additional column to the dataframe that contains a new list based on the addition of `List_A` and `List_B` as so:

```
   A   B    C   List_A     List_B      List_add
   10  10   5   [0, 5, 1]  [10, 12, 0] [10, 17, 1]
   5   7    8   [6, 7, 4]  [5, 2, 1]   [11, 9, 5]
  ...
```

I have made multiple attempts with no avail. Some examples I have tried and their resultant errors

```
df['List_add'] = [x + y for x, y in zip(df['List_A'], df['List_B'])]
Error: TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'float' and 'list'
```

and

```
df['List_add'] = np.add(df['List_A'], df['List_B'])
```

results in the concatenation of `List_A` and `List_B` instead of the addition of the two value by value.

Any suggestions on how I may proceed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
df['List_add'] = a[['List_A', 'List_B']].applymap(np.array).values.sum(axis=1)

#       List_A       List_B     List_add
# 0  [0, 5, 1]  [10, 12, 0]  [10, 17, 1]
# 1  [6, 7, 4]    [5, 2, 1]   [11, 9, 5]
```

**EDIT:** 
To answer the comment: 
If you would like to divide every element in the new list you can just do that as follows:

```
DIVISOR = 5
df['List_add'] = a[['List_A', 'List_B']].applymap(np.array).values.sum(axis=1) / DIVISOR

#       List_A       List_B         List_add
# 0  [0, 5, 1]  [10, 12, 0]  [2.0, 3.4, 0.2]
# 1  [6, 7, 4]    [5, 2, 1]  [2.2, 1.8, 1.0]
```

The output of the first answer is a regular 2-Dimensional `numpy` array, which you can apply all the normal functions to (like `sum()` for instance)

Comment: This seemed to work in a way. However, what if I then wanted to divide each value in the new list by a constant?

Comment: @cosmictypist: I added a divison example to my answer

Comment: Thank you!!! I'll accept your answer in a second. I was wondering, if I wanted to divide list_A by list_B, I should be able to use `df['List_divide'] = df[['List_A', 'List_B']].applymap(np.array).values.divide(axis=1)` right?

Comment: As of my knowledge, you cannot divide along an axis in `numpy`, so I suggest you do the following `df['List_divide'] = df['List_A'].apply(np.array) / df['List_B'].apply(np.array)`. This would also work for the sum (by replacing `/ ` with `+`)

Comment: Ah, thank you for helping me understand the numpy arrays better. I appreciate it.

Answer (score 2):

Fix your code

```
df['List_add'] = [[s + t for s,t in zip(x ,y)]for x, y in zip(df['List_A'], df['List_B'])]
df
Out[36]: 
    A   B  C     List_A       List_B     List_add
0  10  10  5  [0, 5, 1]  [10, 12, 0]  [10, 17, 1]
1   5   7  8  [6, 7, 4]    [5, 2, 1]   [11, 9, 5]
```

Comment: I think this is exactly what I'm looking for. I plan on doing so more slightly complicated  calculations with the lists in the near future. I'm testing this now and I will accept this answer if it works out!

Comment: I got this error `TypeError: zip argument #1 must support iteration`

Answer (score 0):

Here I used a simple code for this problem:

```
df['List_add'] = list()
i = 0

while i < len(df['List_A']):
    df['List_add'].append(df['List_A'][i] + df['List_B'][i])
    i += 1
```